Push notification for apns xmpp server with p2 push proxy
Hi everyone We are using ejabberd xmpp server and for push notifications I deployed this https://github.com/iNPUTmice/p2 module I am running a p2 proxy and is working fine with Android fcm but there is no any documentation or detail for how it will work for APNS we are trying to send the same stanza that used for android but it shows service unavailable. can anyone guide me what's is the issue? why it is not working for APNS?
